# Why SaveChanges() save only modification of existing rows, but not deleted or added entries?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

use; c#, .net 4.5 vs 2012 winforms

Try to use EntityFramework for saving some new data to database, that already binded to dataGridview.

For showing data from db in dataGridView use code below:

For all method use

```
LibraryLib.LibraryEntities context = new LibraryLib.LibraryEntities();
```

In one method i call this :

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = typeof(LibraryLib.Book);
context.Book.ToList().ForEach(n => bs.Add(n));
dataGridViewDB.DataSource = bs;

BindingSource bstab2 = new BindingSource();
bstab2.DataSource = typeof(LibraryLib.LibraryStock);
context.LibraryStock.ToList().ForEach(n => bstab2.Add(n));
dataGridViewCategoryDB.DataSource = bstab2;
```

In another method use next code for saving data (calling by pressing button after changes):

```
context.SaveChanges();
context.Dispose();
```

My db diagramm

[image]

Result -

I can see all my database entries in dataGridview's.

I can change any cell, if save - all saved. But, if i add new item or delete existing one (in both tables - meand remove depended entries from both tables) this changes not saved?
When entering data all required formats for data (mean varchar or int) - ok.

As I read - I can bind data to datagridView then modify it, add or delete any entries and then just save it using method from `ObjectSet` saveChanges()? A'm I right?

**Question** why I have issue with saving my updated (addding or deleting) data and where I'm wrong?

---

**EDIT**

Many thanks for help to **potehin143**

I solve the problem with a little bit another method - create few methods for adding and delting entries from DatdBase

Due to my programm design View, i try to use common logic for all type of engine (mean such function as Add, Remove, Update entries in Library)

[image]

For Adding code next :

```
public void AddNewBookEF()
    {
        string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        LibraryLib.LibraryStock newCat = new LibraryLib.LibraryStock();
        newCat.ID = id;
        newCat.Category = listBoxShelfDB.Text;
        context.LibraryStock.Add(newCat);

        LibraryLib.Book newBook = new LibraryLib.Book();
        newBook.ID = id;
        newBook.Author = textBoxAuthorDB.Text;
        newBook.Name = textBoxNameDB.Text;
        newBook.Year = Int32.Parse(numericUpDownYearDB.Value.ToString());
        newBook.Genre = textBoxGenreDB.Text;
        context.Book.Add(newBook);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

For Removing entryes from DB prepare code like below:

```
public void RemoveFromDBEF(string bookId)
    {
        if (dataGridViewDB.SelectedRows.Count == 1)
        {
            LibraryLib.Book bookToDelete = new LibraryLib.Book();
            bookToDelete.ID = bookId;

            foreach (LibraryLib.Book entry in context.Book)
            {
                if (entry.ID == bookId)
                    context.Book.Remove(entry);
            }
            foreach (LibraryLib.LibraryStock entry in context.LibraryStock)
            {
                if (entry.ID == bookId)
                    context.LibraryStock.Remove(entry);
            }
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select only one row for deleting in Book table");
        }
    }
```

bookId - Guid identificator, that converted in string and saved to DB (When i start to prepare programm i don't know about existing Guid type in DB, so desided do not rewrite all code for this programm, i'm just studing now). For finding bookId for selected book in DataGridView use code like below:

```
    private string GetGuidAsString()
    {
        try
        {
    ...
            if (this.tabControlEngines.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                //get selected number of cell
                int index = dataGridViewDB.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
                //get selected row
                DataGridViewRow selectedBook = dataGridViewDB.Rows[index];
                string guidOfBook = Convert.ToString(selectedBook.Cells[0].Value);
                return guidOfBook;
            }
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a book or add books to empty lib", "No book selected");
            return null;
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        return null;
    }
```

Maybe this answer can be helpfull for some one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 different places where references to dataitems are stored
 context and bindingsorce

so if you add something to binding sorce you need to add the same item to context 
and the same with removing

if you just add item to bindingsorce by DataGridView your context don't know about it

try do this

```
// Here is Example for Book Entity


 context.Book.ToList().ForEach(n => bs.Add(n)); 
 // attach event after fill data
 bs.ListChanged += bs_ListChanged;


void bs_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.ListChangedType)
        {
            case ListChangedType.ItemAdded:
                context.Book.Add((Book)((BindingSource)sender).List[e.NewIndex]); // Adding to Navigating Collection 
                break;

            case ListChangedType.ItemDeleted:
                contextBook.Remove((Book)((BindingSource)sender).List[e.OldIndex]);
                break;
        }

    }


//detaching events for reloading data 
bs.ListChanged -= bs_ListChanged;
// here reloading data from dbase
bs.ListChanged += bs_ListChanged;
```

The relations beetween entities looks like one to one so it may be you need another way to 
add and remove data of both entities by join class like this

```
public class JoinClass
{
    private Book _Book;
    private LibraryStock _LibraryStock;
    public Book GetBook() { return _Book; }
    public LibraryStock GetLibraryStock() { return _LibraryStock; }

    public JoinClass()
    {
        _LibraryStock = new LibraryStock();
        _Book = new Book();
        _LibraryStock.Book = _Book;
    }
    public JoinClass(LibraryStock libraryStock)
    {
        _LibraryStock = libraryStock;
        _Book = libraryStock.Book;
    }

 // here properties of both entities

}
```

and then you may use one BindingSorce and one eventhandler

Comment: I have a question - do I need add this event to both tables (due to possibility of cahnging both tables) if yes - try to add this event to both binding sources. Result - if before i add or delete items - context was the same - now it's updating with added items (in both tables) but, if I try to save it - has exception - DUpdateException.

Comment: Also if i add anly to one table data - context add 1 entity, but if oto both tables (first create some key value and than some book with this key value in another table) context became like context+=context- mean if i have 2 entry after changes i'll have 4 entries. And again - during saving has DBUpdate Exception.

Comment: Also another question - why for updating any cell from existing db i can do this without any events, but for adding or deleting entries i need to use event? Why it's so?

Comment: Would you guys mind to keep any results of this discussion visible here, maybe in an edited answer?

Comment: Gerd, yes sure we will publish all results. The question was why visual collection changes have no effect to context collection. And the answer was that it needs to handle BindingSource Collection changing and add(remove) new(old) items in DbContext. The reason of troubles are in that how to add entity items into Context correctly. This is another topic, but I have asked author to send me details of entity classes to debug it by myself. And soon we will publish edited question and edited answer.

Comment: @Gerd hi, i found some solution, probably not the best, but i'm just studing - next will be better.

Comment: Another possible solution is based on ObservableCollections as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4621033/1977778